# Setting a margin for NavigationDrawer items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My problem is that I can't correctly set up the margin in my navigation drawer. I have tried changing margin of any view and item but it doesn't seem to work out. All I get is space between the ActionBar and NavigationDrawer (and the beginning of the page). I think that the problem is inside my ListItem layout but I am not sure. This is a photo of what I get

[image]

And this is my layout and code files.

### Main Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/refreshSites"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sitesList"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="#FFF">
    </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#222"/>
```

### My piece of code that works with NavigationDrawer

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);   
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles)); //mPlanetTitles is String array
```

**So the question is: How do I set these margins correctly?**

Comment: Don't use margins, use padding instead, i think this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:text="bla bla bla" />
```

and main xml as this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/refreshSites"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sitesList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope, this will help.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The problem was in using margin instead of padding. To be honest, it's a shame I didn't know the difference earlier but I hope now I will remember that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Using the help of Theme.add theme in DrawerLayout.

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Hope, this will help.