# Set the distance between the menu in a navigation drawer and the screen edge?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to set the distance "d" to a specific value, how can I make it?

[image]

Yes, the question [How to programatically set the margin between icon and title of menu item of Navigation Drawer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058219/how-to-programatically-set-the-margin-between-icon-and-title-of-menu-item-of-nav) is just the same as mine. My code is as follows:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_product"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_product"
            android:title="Products" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_statistic"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_statistic"
            android:title="Statistic" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="Log out" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: custom menu layout?

Comment: But I didn't find the default menu layout...

Comment: How are you doing it right now? Using `NavigationView`? Could you show us your code?

Comment: simply customize your own item layout

Comment: That drawer on the left is a ListView and you need to add some padding .. maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869676/setting-a-margin-for-navigationdrawer-items

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058219/how-to-programatically-set-the-margin-between-icon-and-title-of-menu-item-of-nav

Comment: I've added some other info in my question:)

Comment: have you tested  android:paddingLeft="20dp" in NavigationView?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. If you set that, all the views will move right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me:)

In NavigationView for Padding  between the screen and the icon menu :

```
app:itemHorizontalPadding="40dp"
```

and for padding between the menu icon and the text use this:

```
app:itemIconPadding="28dp"
```

full code:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
            app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            app:itemIconPadding="28dp"
            app:itemHorizontalPadding="40dp"  >
```